# Windows phone 8.1 development

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, 32-bit

I have a 32 bit Windows 8.1 on my Asus transformer book. I cannot test my Windows Phone Apps with the emulator because it is not supported. I would like to know how can I test the apps that I create if I don't own a Windows Phone device to connect to my tablet.

Thank you for your time, it is really appreciated !

Happy new year to everyone

Comment: you can't my dear friend, If you really want to develop a good app please create your development environment first.

Comment: I've did some digging quickly, and it seems youi were right! I have found the answer to my query, but I thank you for your comment. It is really appreciated to see fellows dev helping us out ! :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems that debugging on the emulator with a 32 bit OS could only work when working with the Windows Phone 7. As of now, owning a 32 bit OS with Windows 8.1 means that we can only debug with an actual device.

The 32 bit does not support Hyper-V which is needed to use emulators in the OS. Knowing this, I have the following options :

1. Get a new computer because this one is a secondary machine
2. Use virtualbox to simulate a 64 bit windows 8.1 OS

To use the second option, there are some requirements to know about before going too deep into it such as having a 64-bit processor. If you don't have that to begin with, it will not work.

More on virtualizing 64-bit images on 32-bit machines here https://askubuntu.com/questions/180761/can-i-use-virtualbox-with-a-64-bit-image-in-a-32-bit-host